# How can I check for errors in CRUD operations using GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

The [official documentation](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/wiki/Basic-CRUD) for GORM demonstrates a way in which one can test for the existence of a record, i.e.:

```
user := User{Name: "Jinzhu", Age: 18, Birthday: time.Now()}

// returns true if record hasn’t been saved (primary key `Id` is blank)
db.NewRecord(user) // => true

db.Create(&user)

// will return false after `user` created
db.NewRecord(user) // => false
```

This can be used to test indirectly for errors in record creation but reports no useful information in the event of a failure.

Having checked the [source code for `db.Create`](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/callback_create.go#L21), there seems to be some sort of stack-frame inspection that checks for errors before proceeding, meaning that transactional errors will fail silently:

```
func Create(scope *Scope) {
    defer scope.Trace(NowFunc())

    if !scope.HasError() {
        // actually perform the transaction
    }
}
```

- Is this a bug, or am I missing something?
- **How can/should I be informed of a failed transaction?**
- Where can I get useful debugging information?

Comment: does not say that it does not belong here, but have you tried to ask this question at a github of this gorm?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`DB.Create()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Create) returns a new (cloned) [`gorm.DB`](http://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB) which is a `struct` and has a field `Error`:

```
type DB struct {
    Value        interface{}
    Error        error
    RowsAffected int64
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

You can store the returned `*gorm.DB` value and check its `DB.Error` field like this:

```
if dbc := db.Create(&user); dbc.Error != nil {
    // Create failed, do something e.g. return, panic etc.
    return
}
```

If you don't need anything else from the returned `gorm.DB`, you can directly check its `Error` field:

```
if db.Create(&user).Error != nil {
    // Create failed, do something e.g. return, panic etc.
    return
}
```

Comment: This error checking doesn't work at least with current gorm. See answer by @windyzboy and my comment there.

Comment: @gavv You're right, this doesn't work anymore. I tried to delete the answer, but cannot (because it's accepted), so I just edit it.

Comment: Works with v1.9.10.

Answer (score 19):

I have tried the accepted answer, but it doesn't work, `db.Error` always return `nil`.

Just change something and it works, hope it helps somebody:

```
if err := db.Create(&Animal{Name: "Giraffe"}).Error; err != nil {
   // Create failed, do something e.g. return, panic etc.
   return 
}
```

Comment: Correct. The accepted answer doesn't work because `Create` returns a clone of `DB` and `Error` field is set in that clone instead of original object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check type of error, just do it.

```golang
if err := db.Create(&user).Error; err != nil {

  if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }

  return

}
```